# What harm, if any, does epoxy paint do to rope?

Tags: safety, ropes, maintenance

I use ropes to paint Silos. We use epoxy paint which invariably contaminates the ropes. Has there been any tests on these ropes for paint contamination

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what kind of ropes you use?

Comment: Related: [Things to keep away from climbing ropes](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1635/3602). This suggests that epoxy itself is probably not a problem (no actual testing done though), other chemicals in the paint (solvents) may well be damaging the rope.

Comment: Are these LSK (low-stretch kernmantle; "static") ropes?  What material?  There's a big difference in chemical resistance between nylon, polyester, polypropylene, etc.  Some solvents will destroy one kind of rope, leaving another untouched, *and vice versa*.  So it's worth saying what kind of solvent is in the paint.

Answer (score 1):

The issue:  hard gunk on the rope decreases flexibility of the rope.  Fibers may break when the gunk spot is flexed.

My suspicion:  Kernmantle ropes will suffer less than conventional laid ropes.

Test:  Take 3 feet off the end of your rope.  Soak it in your paint, and allow to cure.  Flex repeatedly.  Test to breaking.

Note:  You may find some help by lubricating the rope, or spraying it with silicone so that the paint doesn't wet the surface of the rope.